# Eclipse Stop Auto Complete text from being white

Tags: eclipse

When pressing ctrl space to auto complete a method call, the list of methods displayed looks fine except the one that is currently selected. The font is turned white making it unreadable. What configuration option exists to change this? I cannot find a reference to this UI element anywhere in the settings.

I would screenshot this issue but it's not possible due to the popup becoming almost see through when the print screen key is pressed.

Comment: Using Eclipse Juno and Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify it here : `Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Appearance` > `Colors and Fonts`. You cannot change font color but you can do it for the background.

Comment: No matter what colour the background is, it's still very hard to read when the over hover is a light colour and the text is white. What is the hover over colour called in the properties?